# Creating ImageView array programmatically Android

Tags: android

I have an activity contains `String` array, each `String` is a `drawable` image name, for example if I have an image called "abcd" then in the `String` array the first value will be "abcd". I am trying to pass this `String` array to another activity and then show there all the images.

First Activity:

```
            Intent ip = new Intent(main3.this, main4.class);
            ip.putExtra("p", usedcards1);
            startActivity(ip);
```

Second Activity:

```
        ImageView[] usedcardss;
        RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main4con);
        usedcardss = new ImageView[8];
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for (int i = 0; i < usedcardss.length; i++)
            usedcardss[i] = new ImageView(this);
        Intent pp = this.getIntent();
        String[] cards = pp.getStringArrayExtra("p");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(cards[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
            usedcardss[i].setImageResource(icon);
            usedcardss[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
            rel.addView(usedcardss[i]);
        }
```

A new activity is created but it's simply blank. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is not directly related to your issue but you are using a relative layout and im not seeing in your code where you are setting image layout parameters so that will cause imageViews to overlaps